# C# Mongodb get cursor count

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to find out if a document exists in a collection using the code below. Whenever the query doesn't find any documents I get a StackOverflowException. What am I doing wrong with this?

```
MongoServer server = MongoServer.Create(connectionString);
MongoDatabase db = server.GetDatabase(database);
MongoCollection<Document> documents = db.GetCollection<Document>("Documents");
var query = Query.EQ("DocID", doc.DocID);
var result = documents.FindOneAs<Document>(query);

if (result != null)
{
    doc.Id = result.Id;
    doc.DocCreated = result.DocCreated;
    doc.DocCreatedBy = result.DocCreatedBy;
    doc.MergeFiles(result);
    documents.Save(doc);
}
else
{
    doc.Save();
}
```

Also I am using the official mongodb c# driver.

**Edit:**
Here is the stack trace. It doesn't really say much.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.dll
Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.

**Edit 2:**
Here is a link to my document class.
https://gist.github.com/68d38bec41ebc46f30eb

Comment: Twisternhra: That's not a stack trace, that's the error message. If you're doing this in visual studio (and running in debug mode), you should get an exception handler with a "Copy exception detail to the clipboard". Paste the text that you get copied there.

Comment: Thats what I did. Visual Studio wasnt giving me any information about what happen.
Actually I figured out what the problem was. I accidentally called the wrong Save method and that sent me in an endless loop. For some reason It only stepped through the loop when I set my breakpoint in a certain spot.

Comment: What does doc.Save() do?  Show that code.  Also set some breakpoints and see if this code is getting called over and over (infinite loop), as that is the most likely cause.

Comment: Can you please show code of DocumentData class?

Answer (score 1):

Your else condition doesn't seem to involve any mongo related code.  doc.Save() calls DocumentData.Save passing this (Document) as an argument.  I can only guess that somewhere in that call chain it eventually calls back do Document.Save again.